# How to write a simple while true loop in Erlang for a receive call

Tags: functional-programming, erlang

I am iterating over a list that comes from a receive call.

```
{ok, Pid} = riakc_pb_socket:start_link("server", 8087).
riakc_pb_socket:ping(Pid).
riakc_pb_socket:stream_list_keys(Pid, <<"test">>).
%% while receive, repeat this:
receive Msg1 -> Msg1 end.
{_, {_, List}} = Msg1.
lists:map(fun(K) ->  riakc_pb_socket:delete(Pid, <<"test">>, K) end, List).
```

I am wondering if I could write a simple loop that goes until the receive returns nothing. I also just re-learned that Erlang shell does no let you define functions so I am working on the non-shell version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have a sort of `while` loop, you need to use recursion, as a receive alone is not looping-accumulating messages.
`receive` however loops through *the inbox*. That is it tries to get the first message corresponding to the pattern provided (here, `Msg1`).

So you will have to do something like this

```
gather (0, Acc) ->
    lists:reverse(Acc);  && Just Acc if you don't care about the order.
gather (N, Acc) ->
    receive
        Msg1 -> gather(N -1, [Msg1|Acc])
    end.
gather(10). %% If you are waiting for 10 messages.
```